# Prevent colorbox instance from closing

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Is it possible to prevent colorbox from being closed?  I am using as a loading screen for a server side processing script and don't want it to be closed until finished.

```
$(function(){
    $("#songPayBtn").click(function() {

        $("#ccResultDiv").show();

$.fn.colorbox({width:"50%",
    height:"50%",
    inline:true,
    href:"#ccResultDiv",
    onClosed:function(){ <?php echo "window.location = \"http://rt.ja.com/trackdownload.php?trackid=" . $_SESSION['trackid'] . "\"";?> }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent your colorbox from closing and hide the close button by adding these options:

```
$("#myColorbox").colorbox({
    escKey: false, //escape key will not close
    overlayClose: false, //clicking background will not close
    closeButton: false // hide the close button
});
```

This will also allow you to still use the `$.colorbox.close()` method when you are ready to close your colorbox.

Comment: It would also appear from the docs that there is a parameter to hide the close button -  closeButton: false,

Comment: @mjr, right you are!  Haven't used it myself for a while. Great stuff, thanks for pointing out the update!

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed.  You can redefine the close method before anything is initialized:

```
$.fn.colorbox.close = function(){};
```

This has to occur before the `$(document).ready()` function since it's during this that colorbox will take care of assigning its close method to elements and events.

Comment: This no longer has to be done before DOM ready, it can be done at any time.  But that was exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: @Jack thanks and I appreciate the work you've done on this plugin.  Definitely helped me out on a few projects.